# Как настроить таблицу QTableWidget по ширине?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Примечание ( само окно фиксировано в размере).

Имеется таблица в таком виде сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит растяжение последней ячейки, но как видите, если текста там много, то он обрезается и его никак не просмотреть.
Если убрать растяжение и поставить, например :

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(6,QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

то казалось, бы всё будет нормально, но при наличии в последней ячейке малого количества текста это выглядит убого: (таблица обрезана).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно настроить ее так, чтобы всё отображалось красиво?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После заполнения таблицы можно найти самый длинный текст и подстроить минимальную ширину секции под его длину:

```
QString s = "САМАЯ ДЛИННАЯ СТРОКА"; // нам понадобится текст самой длинной строки
QFontMetrics m(this->font()); // и метрики шрифта
QRect textRect = m.boundingRect(QRect(0,0,0,0),Qt::TextWordWrap,s); // Найдем геометрические параметры текста (высота/ширина в пикселях) с учетом перевода строк
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setMinimumWidth(textRect.width()); // Теперь можно установить минимальную ширину
```

При установленом StretchLastSection, подогнать ширину под содержимое можно двойным кликом тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

> stretchLastSection : bool
>
> Это свойство указывает, занимает ли последний видимый раздел в заголовке все доступное пространство.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#stretchLastSection-prop

Comment: Спасибо, но Вы невнимательно прочитали вопрос. Первый скриншот таблицы - стоит растяжение последней секции. Оно же ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);. При таком варианте у меня обрезается текст в ячейке (три точки на конце) и теперь этот текст уже никак не прочитать. Единственный вариант - расширить окно. Но мне не нужно его расширять. я не могу справиться именно с этой проблемой.

Answer (score 1):

У вас задается подгон по содержимому. для растяжения на все доступное пространство (так можно растянуть не только последний столбец):

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(6, QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

Более подробно о возможных см описание enum QHeaderView::ResizeMode в документации: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum

Если столбец последний, то как и советуют в предыдущем ответе:

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но Вы невнимательно прочитали вопрос. Первый скриншот таблицы - стоит растяжение последней секции. Оно же ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);. При таком варианте у меня обрезается текст в ячейке (три точки на конце) и теперь этот текст уже никак не прочитать. Единственный вариант - расширить окно. Но мне не нужно его расширять. я не могу справиться именно с этой проблемой.

Comment: Двойной клик в заголовке на разделителе расширяет столбец чтобы вместить содержимое. Если же надо расширить "автоматом", то см. еще один ответ

Comment: Очень благодарю за доп. ответ! Еще небольшой вопрос про двойной клик. У меня не вышло. Возможно должен стоять какой-то параметр? (например, editTriggers стоит у меня на NoEditTriggers). Просто возможно я что-то не настроил, потому что, как я уже сказал, у меня совсем никак не получается получить доступ к полному содержимому ячейки...

Comment: вставил картинку в ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо, получилось! :)